# How can I fix my fetch() method so it doesn't return an NullPointerException error?

Tags: data-structures, nullpointerexception, fetch

```html
public class ListingStudent{


    private Listing[] data; 
    private int next;
    private int size;

   public ListingStudent()
   { 

       next=0; 
       size=100;
       data= new Listing[size];
    } 

   public boolean insert(Listing newListing)
   {

      if(next>= size)
        return false;
       data[next]= newListing.deepCopy();
    
        if(data[next] == null)
          return false;
         next= next + 1; 
         return true; 
    } 

   public Listing fetch(String targetKey){ 

     Listing student; 
     Listing temp; 
    
    int i=0; 
    while(i < next && !(data[i].compareTo(targetKey) == 0))
    { 
       i++; 
    } 
    if(i == next) 
     return null; 
    
    student= data[i].deepCopy();

    if(i != 0)
    { 
         temp = data[i-1]; 
         data[i-1] = data[i]; 
         data[i] = temp; 
    } 
     return student;
     
   }
 
  public boolean delete(String targetKey) 
  { 
     int i = 0; 
     while(i < next && !(data[i].compareTo(targetKey)==0))
     { 
        i++; 
     }
     if(i == next) 
      return false; 
     data[i] = data[next-1];
     data[next-1] = null; 
     next = next - 1; 
     return true; 
  } 

  public boolean update(String targetKey, Listing newListing)
  { 
     if(delete(targetKey) == false) 
      return false;
     else if(insert(newListing) == false)
      return false;
     else 
       return true;
   }
 
  public void showAll()
  { 
     for(int i=0; i < next; i++)
      System.out.println(data[i].toString());
   }

  public static void main(String[] args){ 

      ListingStudent obj1 = new ListingStudent();
      Listing temp;
      
      Listing l1 = new Listing("Terrence", 1, 3.45);
      Listing l2 = new Listing("Roberta", 2, 2.15);
      Listing l3 = new Listing("George", 3, 1.50);
  
       System.out.println(obj1.insert(l1));
       System.out.println(obj1.insert(l2));
       System.out.println(obj1.insert(l3));
  

       temp = obj1.fetch("Roberta");
       System.out.println(temp.toString());
       
       temp = obj1.fetch("Terrence"); 
       System.out.println(temp.toString());

       System.out.println(obj1.delete("George"));
       System.out.println(obj1.delete("Terrence"));
       System.out.println(obj1.fetch("Terrence"));
       

       System.out.println(obj1.update("George", l2 ));
       obj1.insert(l1); 
       System.out.println(obj1.update("Terrence", l3 ));
        
       temp= obj1.fetch("Terrence");
       System.out.println(temp.toString()); 
       
       temp = obj1.fetch("George"); 
       System.out.println(temp.toString());
        
        
  } 
 

 }
```

Hello Everyone, 
My application consists of two classes: one is called Listing which is defined in a separate and the other one is posted here. **The basic working of my application is it should be able to insert, fetch, delete, and update listings into an array.** I have been trying for hours to figure out which one of my fetch calls returns a `NullPointerException`. I understand what the exception means, but shouldn't it display what I want instead of the type error. Can someone please help understand my error in my java application. Thanks! Here is my code.

Comment: I went back and checked my work. It turned out that I was incrementing next by 1 in the delete method instead of decrementing by 1. That fixed my problem, but not it just returns exception in thread "main" error, but doesn't tell me specifically the exception is at.

Comment: If you're getting an exception and you don't know where, the first thing to do is is wrap your main in an exception handler and catch the exception. Perhaps you can get more information from that. If that doesn't work, then single-step your code in the debugger. You'll find out pretty quickly which line contains the error.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Already found out where it was and fixed it. Thanks for the help though!